# plotting a range of data that satisfies conditions in another column in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to python. I have an array with four columns. I want to plot columns 2 and 3, pending that column 1 satisfies a condition. If column 1 does not satisfy this range, it is plotted in the next subplot. I have seen that using the where function can do this - just not sure exactly how to go about it.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[17., 18., 19., 20., 31., 46.],\
[1.52,2.5,2.55,2.56,2.53,2.54],\
[7.04,7.06,9.05,11.08,7.06,11.06],\
[0.,0.,0.,0.,4.,4.]])
```

First round and replace the second column:

```
dataRound = sp.round_(data,1)
data[:,1] = dataRound[:,1]
```

Then locate/plot the two different conditions:

```
if np.where(data[i]==1.5):
    subplot(211)
    plt.scatter(data[:,1],data[:,2])
elif np.where(data[i] ==2.5):
    subplot(212)
    plt.scatter(data[:,1], data[:,2])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that answers your question:

```
t=linspace(0,1000, 1000)
y=sin(0.1*t)
ii=find(t>100)
plot(t[ii],y[ii])
```

Basically with `find` you generate a list of indexes that satisfy the logical condition (t>100) and then use this list.

p.s. put np. and plt. where needed

Update:

Is this what you need? Note, you have to exchange [1,:] instead of [:,1]. Advice - print out what you are doing to be sure.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[17., 18., 19., 20., 31., 46.],\
[1.52,2.5,2.55,2.56,2.53,2.54],\
[7.04,7.06,9.05,11.08,7.06,11.06],\
[0.,0.,0.,0.,4.,4.]])

dataRound = sp.round_(data,1)
data[1,:] = dataRound[1,:]
ax1=plt.subplot(211)
ax2=subplot(212)

ax1.scatter(data[1,data[1,:]<=1.5], data[2,data[1,:]<=1.5], color = 'g')
ax2.scatter(data[1,data[1,:]>=2.5], data[2,data[1,:]>=2.5], color = 'b')
```

if you want to plot 2rd and 3rd column, then:

```
ax1.scatter(data[2,data[1,:]<=1.5], data[3,data[1,:]<=1.5], color = 'g')
ax2.scatter(data[2,data[1,:]>=2.5], data[3,data[1,:]>=2.5], color = 'b')
```

Comment: How would you do this instead for an array? where some of the values in one column may appear in another column even though they should be ignored.

Comment: also, there is no dependency within the array